# What do values besides the field names, and empty {} specify in mongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb

I tried:

```
db.inventory.find({},{'_id':1, 'item':1})
db.inventory.find({},{'_id':2, 'item':2})
db.inventory.find({},{'_id':2, 'item':2000})
```

All three produced same results as follows:

```
> db.inventory.find({},{'_id':1, 'item':1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45087"), "item" : "journal" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45088"), "item" : "notebook" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45089"), "item" : "paper" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508a"), "item" : "planner" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508b"), "item" : "postcard" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04608"), "item" : "journal" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04609"), "item" : "notebook" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460a"), "item" : "paper" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460b"), "item" : "planner" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460c"), "item" : "postcard" }
> db.inventory.find({},{'_id':2, 'item':2})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45087"), "item" : "journal" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45088"), "item" : "notebook" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45089"), "item" : "paper" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508a"), "item" : "planner" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508b"), "item" : "postcard" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04608"), "item" : "journal" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04609"), "item" : "notebook" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460a"), "item" : "paper" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460b"), "item" : "planner" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460c"), "item" : "postcard" }
> db.inventory.find({},{'_id':2, 'item':2000})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45087"), "item" : "journal" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45088"), "item" : "notebook" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45089"), "item" : "paper" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508a"), "item" : "planner" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508b"), "item" : "postcard" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04608"), "item" : "journal" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04609"), "item" : "notebook" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460a"), "item" : "paper" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460b"), "item" : "planner" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460c"), "item" : "postcard" }
>
```

1. What do the values 1, 2, 2000 besides the field name specify? Why are results same?
2. What does the first closed curly bracket specify?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What do the values 1, 2, 2000 besides the field name specify? Why are results same?**

Values 1, 2, 2000 specify Projection and are used to see or not see that field in the query result. They are bool type values, if you put 0, it equals False and you will not see that field in the answer, but if you put 1 (or any number greater than 0), it equals True and you will observe it.

**What does the first closed curly bracket specify?**

First closed bracket specify the query, in your example, you are requesting all documents, and for this reason it always returns the same result

A small example you can see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_projection.htm). 
In the official documentation of Mongodb you can also see this topic [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).
Regrards

Answer (score 1):

In simple words, `{}` means you don't give anything to the pipeline. In your query it means, match all the documents. 1,2 2000 or any positive number is used for projection. If it's 0, then it won't project the field, if it's any positive number other that 0, it will project the field.

Few exampls:

1. `db.inventory.find({},{'_id':1, 'item':1})`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45087"), "item" : "journal" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45088"), "item" : "notebook" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45089"), "item" : "paper" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508a"), "item" : "planner" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d4508b"), "item" : "postcard" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04608"), "item" : "journal" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04609"), "item" : "notebook" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460a"), "item" : "paper" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460b"), "item" : "planner" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be0460c"), "item" : "postcard" }
```

Since it's not matching any criteria, it will produce all the documents that you have.

2. `db.inventory.find({},{'_id':0, 'item':1})`

```
{"item" : "journal" }
{"item" : "notebook" }
{"item" : "paper" }
{"item" : "planner" }
{"item" : "postcard" }
{"item" : "journal" }
{"item" : "notebook" }
{"item" : "paper" }
{"item" : "planner" }
{"item" : "postcard" }
```

Since you are specifying 0 for `_id`, which tells to not to project the `_id` fields

3. `db.inventory.find({'item':'notebook'},{'_id':1, 'item':1})`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67598bee5213484d45088"), "item" : "notebook" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ebfd02b3a3b38a52be04609"), "item" : "notebook" }
```

Since you are telling to match the `item` field with 'notebook' and you are telling to project `_id` and `item` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Your first bracket sets the filtering criteria. If you put

```
collection.find({"item" : "journal"})
```

It would only return documents that have journal for the item key.

The second bracket tells Mongo what key, values you want to get back.

```
collection.find({"item" : "journal"}, {"item" : "", "subject" : ""})
```

It would only return _id, item and journal key, values where the item key is journal.
The SQL equivalent is

```
SELECT _id, item, subject FROM table WHERE item = 'journal';
```

The second bracket is optional, leaving it blank is the SQL equivalent of using

```
SELECT *
```